# Install Ubuntu with BTRFS and more subvolumes

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs

I want to install an Ubuntu Server 11.10 with a BTRFS filesystem (in a RAID1 way).

The problem is that I can't see the option in the installer to make more subvolumes. The installer creates two by default: @ and @home, and I want to separate also @var @tmp...

Is there any option to do this? Maybe with the shell... but I think the installer doesn't understand the subvolumes feature of btrfs, so you can't mount each partition in each subvolume...

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to boot into the live DVD.  Then you use the shell to set up your hard drives as you would wish, with mkfs.btrfs (and cryptsetup/LUKS, if you want to do that).  Once done you use the installer, which you see as an icon on the desktop, to install into that drive setup.  Before shutting down, you will have to mount the new install and edit the fstab correctly for the subvolumes (also cryptab, if you use cryptsetup).  Then you chroot ("pivot") into the new install, which allows you to use update-initramfs on that new install.  Depending on your drive setup, you may also have to update-grub.  Once that's done, you're ready to shutdown, removing the install media, and reboot.

If you have any trouble on reboot, you may have to debug by iteration: reboot into the live DVD, remount, edit, update-initramfs, shutdown, remove media and reboot.

Comment: i agree in the way you like to do, the other Option is usally the manual Part to create that during the setup not as primär but as logical psrtions that might also work, but i cant under stand for what reason you would like to do so?

Comment: Sorry @djdomi, but I'm having trouble understanding your question.  The reason to do what I described, is to set up btrfs-RAID with various subvolumes (also, if desired, more complicated settings for cryptsetup), since the installer has a limited partitioner.